# repeating row by splitting particular columns value

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, row

folks, I have a file like this:

```
Sequence ID TFBS_ID Binding sequence    TF_family   TF ID
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0009 taaaTTATTt  AT-Hook AT4G35390
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0009 aAATAAatat  AT-Hook AT4G35390
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0022 atcGGTAAct  Trihelix    AT5G28300
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt  Homeodomain;bZIP;HD-ZIP AT3G61890
```

I want to repeat entire row by splitting TF_family column which has more than single family separated by ";" and I want output like this, any help:

```
Sequence ID TFBS_ID Binding sequence    TF_family   TF ID
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0009 taaaTTATTt  AT-Hook AT4G35390
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0009 aAATAAatat  AT-Hook AT4G35390
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0022 atcGGTAAct  Trihelix    AT5G28300
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt  Homeodomain AT3G61890
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt  bZIP    AT3G61890
CaCLV3_1    TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt  HD-ZIP  AT3G61890
```

Comment: you'll get help if you add the code you tried to solve this

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR==1{print}NR>1{split($4,a,";"); for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){$4=a[i]; print $0}}' file
```

The output:

```
Sequence ID TFBS_ID Binding sequence    TF_family   TF ID
CaCLV3_1 TFmatrixID_0009 taaaTTATTt AT-Hook AT4G35390
CaCLV3_1 TFmatrixID_0009 aAATAAatat AT-Hook AT4G35390
CaCLV3_1 TFmatrixID_0022 atcGGTAAct Trihelix AT5G28300
CaCLV3_1 TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt Homeodomain AT3G61890
CaCLV3_1 TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt bZIP AT3G61890
CaCLV3_1 TFmatrixID_0025 tcAATCAatt HD-ZIP AT3G61890
```

---

- `NR==1{print}` - print the first line as is
- `split($4,a,";")` - split the 4th field by `;`
- `for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){$4=a[i]; print $0}` - repeat currect record for each subvalue